# Where can I find a tutorial for Prestashop theming system?

Tags: php, prestashop, theming

I am trying to create a theme for prestashop.

What I cannot find is why, how and which tpl elements are there available or how can I use them together. PrestaWiki isn't of much help. I am desperate.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=prestashop%20theming%20tutorial) reveals [Creating a Prestashop 1.3 Theme Part 1](http://www.techietips.net/creating-prestashop-13-theme.html)

Comment: Google ... now theres an amazing website .... great find :-)

Comment: I am looking for a Presta 1.4 theming guide. I think I am aware of that "Google" thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the designer guide : http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Designer+Guide

You can also try PrestaShop forums, there are sections dedicated to integration/theme creation.